# Installing a module via pip for python

Tags: 14.04, command-line, software-installation, python3, pip

I tried to install 'PyGreSQL' (pgdb) module via pip3 in Ubuntu 14.04.3 (x86_64)

```
pip3 install PyGreSQL
```

but I have an error:

```
Downloading/unpacking PyGreSQL
Downloading PyGreSQL-5.0.4.tar.gz (637kB): 637kB downloaded
Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/PyGreSQL/setup.py) egg_info for package PyGreSQL
/bin/sh: 1: pg_config: not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
File "/tmp/pip_build_root/PyGreSQL/setup.py", line 88, in <module>
pg_version = pg_version()
File "/tmp/pip_build_root/PyGreSQL/setup.py", line 82, in pg_version
match = re.search(r'(\d+)\.(\d+)', pg_config('version'))
File "/tmp/pip_build_root/PyGreSQL/setup.py", line 74, in pg_config
raise Exception("pg_config tool is not available.")
Exception: pg_config tool is not available.
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
/bin/sh: 1: pg_config: not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
File "/tmp/pip_build_root/PyGreSQL/setup.py", line 88, in <module>
pg_version = pg_version()
File "/tmp/pip_build_root/PyGreSQL/setup.py", line 82, in pg_version
match = re.search(r'(\d+)\.(\d+)', pg_config('version'))
File "/tmp/pip_build_root/PyGreSQL/setup.py", line 74, in pg_config
raise Exception("pg_config tool is not available.")
Exception: pg_config tool is not available.
```

- `python --version` - Python 3.4.3
- `which pip3` - `/usr/bin/pip3`

Can you please help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are facing the following error:

> Exception: pg_config tool is not available.

The `pg_config` tool is part of [`libpq-dev`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/libpq-dev/)

You can install it using:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

Comment: @Oleksii - great! If my answer solve your question, please [accept](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) it